# Allow formatting when displaying text from asp:TextBox input

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms, formatting

I have an input text box where users can enter html formatted text. I then have another method which pulls the text from the database and displays it on an asp:label. If you enter html into the text box now, the page gives an error..

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

<asp:TextBox ID="txtEditBody" class="txtBody" runat="server" Wrap="True" MaxLength="5000"
TextMode="MultiLine" />
```

How can I get the text to be formatted? or create my own type of simple formatting codes. Would I have to parse the entire input before displaying it on a label? will an asp label display html formatted text?

Answer (score 0):

You can set at page directive `ValidateRequest="false"` to resolve this problem.

Comment: How can i get the asp label to keep line breaks etc without actually adding <br />'s?

Comment: You can't get it without <br />'s

Answer (score 0):

This happens when asp.net detect that input control is trying to post html or javascript data so you can set the page ValidateRequest="false" so the asp.net will not check if the input fields contains html data.

Comment: Yes, the asp label will render the html.